# Can a switch statements have functions with arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, function, switch-statement

I have a script I am working on which has switch with function.

I wish create cases upon keyCodes and to execute the correct method with arguments.
   the keycodes can be 'C' OR 'P' otherwise 'Invalid' will be prompt.

```
class Switcher(object):
def indirect(self, code):
    method_name = 'method_' + str(code)
    method = getattr(self,method_name, lambda: 'Invalid')
    return method()

def method_C(self,title):
    return 'method_C'  + title


def method_P(self,title):
    return 'method_P'  + title
```

My main() is as follows :

```
s = Switcher()
func = s.indirect('C')
a = func("I'm at Method_C")
print(a)
```

I'm getting exception while trying to pass to generated method an arguments

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

related to line of code :  a = func("I'm at Method_C")

ANY IDEAS ?

Comment: `s.indirect('C')` returns the result of calling the method, not the method itself, so naming it `func` and trying to call it doesn't make sense.

Comment: got u! it needs to be handle inside the indirect method. so how can i switch functions with arguments ?

Comment: Please try to explain clearly what you intend to do, there probably is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I want to call methods based on 1 key parameter & before calling the resulted method to pass an arguments to it.

---

to be more clear i wish to :

```
1. send key = 'C'.
2  the switch will select method_C as result.
3. to call the method_C with string argument (without knowing which method was 
   resulted).
```